# conan build with custom CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I have a CMake project that does not use the standard choices for `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` / `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES`.  This project consumes other libraries which do, however.

How do I make this integration smooth?  Since `build_type` is typically defined as a setting, I can't choose different values for different libs.  So, the only solution that comes to mind is to take all of the packages I need, host them in my own private repository, modify their `conanfile.py` so that they export `build_type` as an option instead of a setting, and then use `conanfile.py` of the library I'm packaging to define the mapping from my configuration types to dependent library configuration types.

`CMakeDeps` appears to support a `configuration` option, but I'm still not sure how to produce a recipe for my package using this.  Let me make a concrete example:

I develop `A`, which has 3 configs (NoOpt, Optimized, Release).  I consume `B` and `C` which both have `Debug` and `Release`.  I would like the mapping to be:

**A=NoOpt:** B=Release, C=Debug

**A=Optimized:** B=Release, C=Release

**A=Release:** B=Release, C=Release

I need to come up with recipes for A, B, and C here so that when I do
`conan install -o build_type=NoOpt` from `A`, it installs `B` in Release and `C` in Debug, while making `conan build` pass `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=NoOpt`.

Comment: The modern build system integrations support custom configuration types, check https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/conanfile/tools/cmake/cmakedeps.html#configuration. If the configuration types are widely used, you might want to add them to the ``settings.yml`` definition too, depending on the usage.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I didn't know CMakeDeps supported that.  But I'm still a little clear on how to use CMakeDeps in conjunction with CMakeToolchain and CMake, so I've updated my post a little bit with a concrete example.

Comment: That is a different issue. The configuration for a package doesn't imply the configuration for dependencies. That needs to be defined at the cli or better, at the profile level (using profiles strongly recommended). You can specify settings per package, like ``-s pkgc:build_type=Debug`` (in the profile without ``-s``). That allows patterns too, like ``pkg*:build_type=Debug``. For conversations, questions can also be filed at https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues.